# recent location wrong after changing stimulator location

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cllocation

I switched my stimulator location from New York, plugged my iPhone and iPad into my mac and then switched my stimulator location back to none.

My CLLocation output on my physical devices has been giving me New York coordinates ever since and i can't get it back. I have reset the location and privacy, restored the devices, turned off location, turned off frequent locations and considered learning magic but none of these solutions have worked. 
Does anyone know of another way to fix this problem?

Comment: You *restored* the devices (as in, to their factory settings)?

Comment: I have but then I put an old backup on.